# Calling finish() from SurfaceView does not destroy Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview

I want to `finish()` the activity `VideoPlayer` from the class `RenderView`. However calling `finish()` from `RenderView` does not call `onDestroy()`. The Activity is not destroyed and does not return back to the previous Main Activity.

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        renderView.pause();     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        naClose2();
    }

}
```

`mFinished = true` but it returns back to the method `parseServerInfo()` where `finish()` was called and continues executing the rest of the code.

**EDIT**

```
public class RenderView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback   {
    private Context mContext;

    private Runnable prDisplayVideoTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(zoomState.isPlaying()==false){
                if(zoomState.getFlag()==FlagType.PAUSE){
                    zoomState.setFlag(FlagType.NONE);
                    naPause();
                }
            } else {
                naStart();
            }
            prVideoDisplayHandler.postDelayed(this, prDelay);
        }
    };

    public RenderView(...) {
        super(_context);
        this.mContext = _context;
        init(address, windowWidth, windowHeight, videoWidth, videoHeight,
                server_ip, server_port);
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void init(...) {
        parseServerInfo(receivedData);
        prVideoDisplayHandler.removeCallbacks(prDisplayVideoTask);
        prVideoDisplayHandler.postDelayed(prDisplayVideoTask, prDelay);
    }

    public void pause(){
        naPause();
        prVideoDisplayHandler.removeCallbacks(prDisplayVideoTask);
    }

    public void resume(){
        prVideoDisplayHandler.postDelayed(prDisplayVideoTask, prDelay);
    }

    public void parseServerInfo(String data) {
        if (numCameras == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No stream detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Finish is called here
            VideoPlayer videoplayer = (VideoPlayer) mContext;
            videoplayer.finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCreated  == true) {
            surfaceDestroyed(holder);
        }
        Surface surface = holder.getSurface();
        render(surface);
        mCreated = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCreated = false;
    }
}
```

Hope someone could help point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am an beginner also. Try getActivity() instead, because you want to finish activity.

Comment: @UmeshChhabra If I am not wrong, its not possible to call getActivity() from SurfaceView. Hence I used getContext() to get the reference to the Activity.

Comment: getContext.getActivity();

Comment: Just use ((VideoPlayer).getContext()).finish(); You don't need to keep an explicit reference to your context, your view already has a reference to it.

Comment: @zgc7009 That was how I had implemented it, I used `mContext` based on the solution suggested. However, both doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Throw in a debug breakpoint to make sure you are hitting that like you would expect

Comment: @zgc7009 'finished()' is called, but it doesn't go on to destroy the activity, it continues executing the remaining code instead

Comment: If you call finish and it doesn't crash you are finishing something. Does the activity ever close?

Comment: @zgc7009 The activity does not close, it continues executing the code, where essentially it is waiting for a response from the server. The activity freezes and pressing back gives a not responding message after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why it is continuing on and freezing up (as mentioned in the comments to your question). It should. That is how the java language works. Here,

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void init(...) {
    parseServerInfo(receivedData);
    ...
}
```

You call `parseServerInfo(receivedData);` which does

```
public void parseServerInfo(String data) {
    if (numCameras == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No stream detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Finish is called here
        VideoPlayer videoplayer = (VideoPlayer)getContext();
        videoplayer.finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

So you are seeing the Toast, getting finish called, and saying good to go. But you aren't looking back at where you came from. With comments, what your init method should say is

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void init(...) {
    // make a call to check that the number of cameras is not 0
    parseServerInfo(receivedData);    
    // AND CONTINUE NO MATTER WHAT...
    prVideoDisplayHandler.removeCallbacks(prDisplayVideoTask);
    prVideoDisplayHandler.postDelayed(prDisplayVideoTask, prDelay);
}
```

What you need is

```
public boolean parseServerInfo(String data) {
    if (numCameras == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No stream detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Finish is called here... AND FALSE IS RETURNED
        VideoPlayer videoplayer = (VideoPlayer) mContext;
        videoplayer.finish();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void init(...) {
    // make a call to check that the number of cameras is not 0
    // AND CONTINUE IF GOOD (TRUE)
    if(parseServerInfo(receivedData)){
        prVideoDisplayHandler.removeCallbacks(prDisplayVideoTask);
        prVideoDisplayHandler.postDelayed(prDisplayVideoTask, prDelay);
    }
}
```

this will parse your data, finish the activity if it should, and then stop progress with your SurfaceView init method. Sorry for so much redundant code but it is just easiest to explain :P

Comment: Changing the structure of the code such as you suggested works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the Activity which you would like to finish inside the `SurfaceView`. You get the context from the constructor of the `SurfaceView` class. Use this to `finish()` your activity, like so

```
//class member
private Context mContext;

public RenderView(...) {
    super(_context);

    //make the context accessible from the whole class
    this.mContext = _context;

    ...
}
```

Finally you call `finish()` on the that context to finish your `VideoPlayer` activity.

Comment: Do you pass the activity context to the RenderView constructor? @miazima